# Cut the string to particular length and preserve whole words

Tags: php

What would be the best way to, given a string `$s` and character limit $l, cut the `$s` so that whole words are preserved.

Example:

```
$s = 'Hello World.';
$l = 7;

function shorten( $a, $b ) { ... }
// Function should return 'Hello'
```

I've tried doing it with `wordwrap( $s, $l, ';;;' );` and then `substr( $s, strpos( ';;;', $l ) );` but that seems awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` will help you here:

```php
$strings = [
  'Word',
  'Length.',
  'Hello World.',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
];
$length = 7;
foreach( $strings as $string ){

  print 
    $string
    . ' => '
    . preg_replace("/(.{{$length}}[^\s]*).*/s", "$1", $string)
    . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Word => Word
Length. => Length.
Hello World. => Hello World.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. => Lorem ipsum
```